# How do I get a package from Electric EMYS to work in Indigo Igloo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to use the MIT Kinect demos for a project.  However, the latest version of the package is designed for Electric EMYS.  Will this work on Indigo, and if so, how do I do it?
Here is the link for the MIT Kinect demos.
http://wiki.ros.org/mit-ros-pkg/KinectDemos

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246505/how-do-i-get-a-package-from-electric-emys-to-work-in-indigo-igloo./) by [scannellstp](https://answers.ros.org/users/28348/scannellstp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-10-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's unlikely that the packages will work out of the box, but it would be possible to manually port them, trying to compile and fix errors as they pop up. Interestingly, [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) states that rosbuild still works for building from source in kinetic, so maybe you would not need to perform [migration to the now standard catkin build system](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild).

In theory, another approach would be to follow all the migration guides from electric up to kinetic one by one (there doesn't seem to be a groovy page):

- http://wiki.ros.org/fuerte/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Migration
- http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Migration

Another good idea might be too google things and look around on github. Often, somebody else had the same idea and there might already be some port to later ROS versions out there.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-10-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [scannellstp](https://answers.ros.org/users/28348/scannellstp/) on 2016-10-26**:
Thank you very much for the help.